# Get variables in scope at each PHP backtrace level?

Tags: php, scope, backtrace

Is there a way to view the variables set in each stack frame in a backtrace? I can come pretty close with a combination of `debug_backtrace(true)` to get the objects, `get_object_vars` on each object to get $this vars, the `args` key in each backtrace frame, and `get_defined_vars` to get globals, but any temporary variables set within a function I can't find a way to retrieve.

Here's an example situation:

```
function method1($foo) {
    $temp = method2($foo + 1);
    foreach ($temp as $t) {
        method2($t);
    }
}

function method2($bar) {
    $temp2 = $bar->value + $_GET['val'];
    debug();
}

function debug() {
    // to be created
    $global_scope = get_defined_vars();
    $bt = debug_backtrace(true);
}
```

I **can** get `$foo` and `$bar` via the `args` key in the backtrace, the object variables of `$bar` through `get_object_vars`, and the globals through `get_defined_vars`. I **want** to get the value of `$temp2` and `$temp` as well.

Comment: Curious what you would need this for.

Comment: Does `XDebug` not do what you need?  Why re-invent a full blown debugger when installing one really really simple?

Comment: As far as I can tell, XDebug can only do the top stack too: "With the xdebug.show_local_vars setting you can instruct Xdebug to show all variables available in the top-most stack level for a user defined function as well." Part of this is so I can quickly inspect values Firebug-style by tying the values to the highlighted source output variables. The other part is just for kicks.

Comment: I can't find anything in [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php) either, unfortunately. [Python can do it](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html), don't see why PHP shouldn't be able to.

Comment: This is what I was looking for too. At least I now know it isn't possible. Unless it is now? It would be a great aid in debugging and seeing exactly where things have gone wrong and where a variable has an unexpected value.

Answer (score 1):

Install and Enable XDebug on your (local) server. Then use [`xdebug_get_declared_vars()`](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_get_declared_vars). Make sure that you set `xdebug.collect_vars` to On in your xdebug `.ini` file.

#### Example:

```
<?php
    class strings {
        static function fix_strings($a, $b) {
            foreach ($b as $item) {
            }
            var_dump(xdebug_get_declared_vars());
        }
    }
    strings::fix_strings(array(1,2,3), array(4,5,6));
?>
```

#### Returns:

```
array
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  2 => string 'item' (length=4)
```

<sup>Example from [xdebug.org](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_get_declared_vars)</sup>

Note, that the function only returns variables in the scope where the function `xdebug_get_declared_vars()` is called in.

Answer (score -1):

Alter your debug to take 1 param. Then just pass in [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/get_defined_vars). This will give you an array of all the vars in the local scope.

Comment: I already used that method to get the local vars, the problem is getting the local vars in the OTHER stack frames.